# Schedule an Excel macro to run at 25 minutes after the hour, unless it was manually run after 00:25

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro that records the time it was run on a worksheet. I want to schedule the macro to run every hour once between 25 minutes and 58 minutes after the hour, unless it was run manually between that time. I've come up with a macro that will handle this but I don't know how to execute the macro, doesn't it need to be running at all times to keep track of things?

```
Sub auto_download()

when = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Now() / TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), 0) * TimeSerial(1, 0, 0) 'current hour

startTime = when + TimeValue("00:25")

lateTime = when + TimeValue("00:58")

myDay = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valu").Range("A66"), 14, 6) 'last updated date string
myMin = Right(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valu").Range("A66"), 5)

myDayDate = CDate(myDay + myMin) 'Serial date of last updated string

If lastUpdated < startTime Then
Application.OnTime startTime, "Download_raw_obs", lateTime
End If
End Sub
```

What is the next step in scheduling this?

Comment: yes, it does need to be running all the time to get it to work. You basically would write a loop that checks the `lastUpdated` concurrently  [Windows Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) can come in handy here, if you don't want to leave the Excel File Open and Running all Day. You could have the macro update a text file when it's run, then have task scheduler run a vbscript every hour that checks the value of that file and run the macro if it needs running.